# Colored Sharepoint Calender issue while clicking "More Item" link

Tags: sharepoint, calendar

I have created a colored sharepoint calender using the following article.

http://www.sharepointbreak.com/2012/09/02/creating-a-color-coded-calendar-by-category-using-js-in-sharepoint-2010/

It is working fine untill we click the 'more item' link. I have a lot of items in calender so while clicking the link to expand the above method is not working.

I hope somebody has some solution to this. Please suggest.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding the following line in the `ColourCalendar()` method:

```
$('.ms-cal-nav').attr('href', 'javascript:ColourCalendar();');
```

This line did the trick and the code is working fine.